# How to determine that Java is running on Windows

Tags: java, operating-system

I wish to determine whether Java is running on Windows, and have seen many different suggestions which include various permutations of the System property `os.name` with  `startsWith` / `indexOf` / `contains` / `toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)` / `toLowerCase()`, or just `File.separatorChar`.

I scanned JDK source code to see whether there was a definitive answer (see below) and a few other SO posts which suggest:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name" /**, "<Surely os.name is never null?>" */);
List<Boolean> isWindows = List.of(
    os.startsWith("Windows"),
    os.contains("Windows"),
    os.toLowerCase().startsWith("windows"),
    os.toLowerCase().contains("windows"),
    os.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains("windows"),
    os.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).startsWith("windows"),
    File.separatorChar == '\\'
);
System.out.println("os.name       ="+os);
System.out.println("os.name(UTF-8)="+Arrays.toString(os.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
System.out.println("isWindows     ="+isWindows);
```

Is there any permutation of OS / language installation which incorrectly identifies `isWindows` using the above conditions, where true/false is inconsistent or wrong?

```
// For Windows I would expect all true, such as:
os.name       =Windows 10
os.name(UTF-8)=[87, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 115, 32, 49, 48]
isWindows     =[true, true, true, true, true, true, true]

// For non-Windows I would expect all false such as:
os.name       =Linux
os.name(UTF-8)=[76, 105, 110, 117, 120]
isWindows     =[false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

**JDK source code examples**

For reference, this is where `isWindows` is detected in Open JDK17 source code (from a recent `git fetch` NOT final release candidate):

src/java.desktop/share/classes/com/sun/imageio/plugins/bmp/BMPImageReader.java

```
    System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("win"));
        
src/java.smartcardio/share/classes/sun/security/smartcardio/CardImpl.java
src/jdk.zipfs/share/classes/jdk/nio/zipfs/ZipFileSystem.java    
src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/JNIWriter.java

    isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows"))

src/java.desktop/share/classes/sun/font/FontUtilities.java

    isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name", "unknownOS").startsWith("Windows");
        
src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipFile.java
src/java.desktop/share/classes/sun/awt/OSInfo.java

    VM.getSavedProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")
    System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")
    
src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/NimbusLookAndFeel.java

    boolean isWindows = osName != null && osName.contains("Windows");
        
src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicFileChooserUI.java

    boolean isWin32 = (File.separatorChar == '\\')
    
src/jdk.jpackage/share/classes/jdk/jpackage/internal/Platform.java
Note that I've omitted this test in case of confusion with Darwin OS:

    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (os.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
        platform = Platform.WINDOWS;
    }
```

Comment: If the developers of the JDK can't agree, what answer do you expect from us?  It seems like `System.getProperty("os.name")` is the better choice of many choices.

Comment: `File.separator` could be used as a 'sanity check' too

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I'm hoping someone can disprove one of the boolean suggestions. I can't put `if(System.getProperty("os.name"))` as one of the choices.

Comment: Do you want the jdk also support a ten or hundred different method for respective system os? like isAix, IsMac, Is.... ? Basically, i think os.name is quite enough ... We can use it to do what we want.

Comment: @huy I'm not expecting JDK to provide a method isWindows (nor isAIX etc). I'm hoping all of those work in every situation so that it does not matter which of the seven I use in my own code.

Comment: I like to simplify the problem, in my project, contains("Win") is enough for me,  why waste too much time to cover all situations... i would like to follow KISS or YAGNI principle :)

Comment: hey just use `if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows"))`

Comment: `System.getProperty("os.name")` is the way to go. However, note that it might not identify correctly the OS flavor or version: with Java 17, I get "Windows 10" on a Windows 10 desktop, "Linux" on a Linux server. So far, so good. With Java 6, I get "OS/2" on ArcaOS (that's correct, though you won't tell the difference between OS/2, eCS and ArcaOS), and on the same Windows 10 desktop I get "Windows 8".

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Thanks. About your OS/2: is `File.separatorChar == '\\'` true?

Comment: @DuncG Yes. And note also that on ArcaOS, the most recent port of Java is currently version 1.6.0_27.

Comment: There's no need for both 'startsWith' and 'contains' -- contains does the job.  There's no need for both case-sensitive and case-blind checks.

Comment: @user16632363 I'm not suggesting running every condition to determine `isWindows`. Either of the first 2 appear perfectly fine. I just want to understand whether there is a justification that some developers suggest permutations with `toLowerCase()` /  `contains` versus just `startsWith()`.

Comment: Oh, I thought you'd copied that example *verbatim* from somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After noting the various comments and other posts, I've not found a reason not to continue using the `isWindows` check I currently have in my code, which is simply the first test listed:

```
boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows");
```

The first six tests in my question appear to detect `isWindows` correctly, but not the last item `File.separatorChar == '\\'` (as that is also true on OS/2).

Note that in Turkish the lower case value of "I" is not equal to "i". Try:

```
"I".toLowerCase(Locale.forLanguageTag("TR")).equals("i") // char:305
"i".toUpperCase(Locale.forLanguageTag("TR")).equals("I") // char:304
```

Maybe this explains why some developers use `.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)` but nothing changes for any of the test results unless `os.name` property is uppercase in Turkish installation.

Thanks for all the suggestions.